# checking password for change password validation in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am working on change password form in website .I want to check whether the password store in database equal to current password request from change password form. I am using node-js and mysql. I want the output as incorrect if current password is not same as Password of user logged in or if its same then should update the password value of that user in database
Below is my code:

controller file:

```
 editprofileService.changePassword(data,(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
           return res.status(400).send({ success: 0, data: "Bad request" });
        }

        return res.redirect("/edit-profile")
    })
}
```

service file:(here fetching the data related work is done in my project)

```
 exports.changePassword = (data, callback) => {
  
  db.query(`SELECT Password FROM user WHERE u_id=? `,
    [data.userid],
    (error, results, feilds) => {
      if (error) {
        return callback(error);
      }
    
      if (results.length > 0) {
      
        if (data.currentPassword == results[0].Password) {
          console.log("hello");
          db.query(
            `UPDATE user SET Password=? where u_id=? `,
            [data.newPassword, data.userid],
            (error, results, fields) => {
              if (error) {
                
                return callback(error);
              }
              if (results.affectedRows > 0) {
                //console.log(results);
                // return callback(null, "Login success");
                console.log(results.affectedRows);
                console.log(results);
                return callback(null, "updated successfuly");

              } else {
                return callback("Invalid credentials");
              }
            }
          );
        }


      }

      else {
        return callback("password incorrect");
      }
    })
}
```

Whenever I run the code and click on change password is goes into continuous loop and does not return anything .Its just hang the server. Buffering like symbol appears on title bar.

Comment: I got ,what's wrong with the code .

Comment: You have a typo in your service file code, line 4 `(error, results, feilds)`.. It's `fields`, right?

Comment: yes its fields its typing error

Comment: but even its not giving output

Comment: When you try with that code, did you see whether console returns the `console.log("hello");` that you've placed in the code?

Comment: I have a piece of code for changing password in node.js but as I see, your operation and mine is not the same. My code require user to enter their old password along with the new password for the code to be passed. Whereas I can see your code is only looking for `SELECT password FROM user WHERE u_id=?`. Won't that be a problem if someone else went to change the password while the person logged in and went out for a bit? Also, it seems like you're storing password as string (as it is) into the table, not encrypted, is that correct?